# Node + PM2 - How to securely read SSL private key with non-root user?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, file-permissions, node.js, private-key

I'm looking for a way to run node via PM2 whilst reading an SSL private-key that is placed in a secure directory.

Details: 
Bitnami LEMP stack with Node

permissions for /etc/ssl/private:

```
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 private
```

permissions for key file:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1704 my_key_file.key
```

With the above permissions, both nginx and php run fine with no problems whatsoever (I'm guessing this is because nginx's *master* process runs as root?), and so does running node as sudo.

However I'd like to run this node code as a non-root user, since this reduces the security risk should the node server be compromised.

What are my options here ? The way I understand it it's something like these options:

- Loosen permissions on private-key folder/file (Bad, involves changes to /etc/ssl/private!)
- Copy private_key and make it readable just by a safe-user that runs pm2 (Bit messy, involves keeping track of copied files for updates etc)
- Run PM2 *master* as root, which then spawns a process/instance as a non-root user (Much like how nginx works, not sure if this is even possible)
- Run PM2 as root, change the code to drop its own privilege level after doing some things as root (as outlined [here](https://thomashunter.name/blog/drop-root-privileges-in-node-js/) - looks slightly messy and also might be a security risk)

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: nginx reads these files and binds to privileged ports as root, and then _drops its privileges_, changing to the nginx user for the rest of the time that it is running. There's no real security issue here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yes I realise that, my question is rather about the _Node_ process running through PM2 - How should one securely run _Node_ through _PM2_ **and** read a private-key for SSL encryption?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a group called `ssl-cert` and add `pm2user` to that group.

```
sudo groupadd ssl-cert
sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert pm2user
```

Then change the group of the directory `/etc/ssl/private` and its contents to be `ssl-cert`. You will also need to add group execute permissions for the `private` directory.

```
sudo chown -R root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/
sudo chmod 650 /etc/ssl/private/
sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/my_key_file.key
```

That will allow access for PM2 to read the file. Is it more or less secure? That may depend on who has access to the server and how widely the `ssl-cert` group is shared. Keep the usage of the group to the absolute minimum: non-login accounts only.
You will probably need to restart the Nginx and PM2 services so they reconnect with the new permissions.